# Defining transpency in bmp files

Tags: javascript, c++, textures, game-engine, babylonjs

A game I'm currently researching, has some textures on interface. Those textures in-game are transparent. This game is honestly really old (1999) and those textures are saved as `.BMP`. Here is a sample texture file:

[Sample texture interface file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRMss.png)

This game is written in C++.

Here's my question: how is that possible, that a game understands some parts of `.BMP`, which are definitely **black**, as a transparent surface? Can you give me an idea, how to define one as well? I'm currently working in canvas (Javascript, [BabylonJS](http://babylonjs.com/)), but I need an idea, not code.

Comment: I mean, once the .BMP file is loaded, the software can display it any way it wants to. If it wants to display red as green, there's nothing stopping it from doing so.

Comment: If the .bmp file contains 32-bit data, each pixel is defined by 4 bytes of component levels: red, green, blue and alpha.  Alpha may be interpreted as the pixel's transparency level.  Unfortunately, the image you linked has been converted to .png, and without the original data I can't draw any conclusions about its format.

Comment: you can loop though the pixels and change that black to transparent.

Comment: @Christopher Oicles I can link original file to some file sharing site